# Finding unanswered questions for a particular tag

Tags: support, usability, search

I there an easy way to do this?

At first I though the tag link from the unanswered tab would do this, but alas no (it shows all questions for that tag), and I can't see anything in the advanced search syntax which would do this (though I guess votes:0 would come close).

TIA,
Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in the search (for the sql tag for example)

```
[sql] hasaccepted:0
```

or

```
[sql] answers:0
```

Put a tag name within square brackets [] to use it as a search axis.  The trilogy definition of "unsanswered" is something without an accepted answer (the first example).  No answers period, see the second example.

Here's how the search became a [**little less crappy**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/), which'll answer a few things about searching the trilogy.

Answer (score 8):

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/xaml